# In mvc application how can I show message one by one like notification?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have an MVC application and I'm registering a device to IOT using a foreach loop.

I want to show messages one by one when one device is done with registration. How can I show the messages on the view?

Code in the controller method -

```
    foreach (var deviceId in collection)
    {
        try
        {
            // save device information into database
            Models.Device newDevice = new Models.Device()
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Device = deviceId
            };

            _deviceRepository.InsertDevice(newDevice);
            _deviceRepository.Save();

        }
        catch (DeviceAlreadyExistsException)
        {
            device = await registryManager.GetDeviceAsync(deviceId);
            ViewBag.Message = "device already present";
        }
    }

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Error";
    throw ex;
}
ViewBag.Message = "device register successfully - " + deviceId;
return View("Index")
```

How can I show `ViewBag.Message` one by one on view or partial view ?

If an error occurs it will display an error message.
If success then one by one like notification we have to show messagesuccess message.

For example I have 10 items then the foreach will run 10 times, after every device success we need to show a message on the UI:

`device register successfully device1`

`device register successfully device2` and so on ...

I know ViewBag won't be useful, what approach can I take?

Comment: Can you explain what you want "show 10 messages one by one"? Note that the `ViewBag` contents are simultaneously sent to view, probably you need to use client-side trick.

Comment: yea i think i need to use some js code here .. when I click on button it will execute this code and after every success execution of foreach i want to show message on UI like this device is successfully register if there are 10 items foreach will execute for 10 times

Comment: You mean that If some user do any action like Register another user, send a notification to every one?

Comment: Nope when a message is saved into database using foreach i just have to show message like device is registered on UI. updated question with more details description

Comment: All you are doing at the moment is overwriting `ViewBag.Message` in each iteration. You need to either create a message for each device, or you need to submit one item at a time (perhaps using ajax)

Comment: What kind of message you're sending? Probably splitting to smaller chunks before displaying one-by-one should help, or use AJAX to check existence of every status messages (current implementation overwrites `ViewBag` with newer message).

Comment: If you want the output as per your edit, then initialize `ViewBag.Message` as an empty `string` and append the messages e.g.  `ViewBag.Message += string.Format("Device {0} successfully registered", i + 1)` (and use a `for` loop)

Comment: ok let me try this also..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you would need to take a different approach for this behaviour.

Look into using signalR so you can communicate with the client side view whilst a server side operation is taking place.

You could use this to show a progression loading bar, or give feedback ever time a device has registered.